# huge memory footprint while adding edges to graph

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, graph, memory-leaks

I have a struct `node` and a class `graph` they are looking like this:

```
struct node {
    node(const std::string &s) : id(std::hash<std::string>()(s)) { }
    node(node &&) = default;
    node(const node &) = default;

    friend bool operator<(node lhs, node rhs){
        return lhs.id < rhs.id;
    }
    mutable bool visited{false};
    const std::size_t id;
    mutable std::set<node> neighbors;
    mutable std::set<node> back_edges;
};

class graph {
    private:
        std::set<node> node_set;
    public:
        size_t add_edge(node from, node to){

            //auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

            auto iter_from = node_set.insert(from).first;
            auto iter_to = node_set.insert(to).first;


            iter_from->neighbors.insert(*iter_to);
            iter_to->back_edges.insert(*iter_from);

            //auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
            //      (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);

            //return duration.count();
            return -1;
        }

        std::size_t size(){
            return node_set.size();
        }

};
```

Now I want to test the `add_edge` method by generating a random graph. For this I have a function which generates random alphanum strings of the length `SIZE`:

```
constexpr size_t SIZE{2};

graph g1;
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
    g1.add_edge(random_string(SIZE), random_string(SIZE));
```

If I choose `SIZE` not too small like more than 5, everything works fine, but if I try to choose `SIZE` small like 2 or even 1 I get a HUGE memory footprint and the test takes forever. Since the graph should be smaller with a smaller `SIZE` (for `SIZE = 1` -> 26^2) I don't really understand why this happens.

EDIT: for smaller `SIZE` the `add_edge` is getting slower and slower each iteration in the loop.

EDIT: here is the function which generates my random strings:

```
std::string random_string(size_t length) {
    static bool initialized{false};
    if (!initialized) {
        std::srand(std::time(0));
        initialized = true;
    }
    auto randchar = []() -> char {
        static const char charset[] =
                "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        const size_t max_index = (sizeof(charset) - 1);
        return charset[std::rand() % max_index];
    };
    std::string str(length, 0);
    std::generate_n(str.begin(), length, randchar);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: How are you measuring the memory footprint? Also, can you show the function to generate random strings?

Comment: the memory footprint is big enougth to freeze my pc and getting out of RAM and Swap ... I can literally see my pc freezing in the system monitors

Comment: Please don't use `srand`/`rand` - they generate very poor random numbers ( https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful ). You should use the facilities in `<random>` instead ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random ).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know but since this isnt a crypto lib I think rand is good enought

Comment: @Exagon I tend to disagree - `rand` is *never* "good enough" it is just plain bad - crypto or no crypto, it should simply never be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently storing copies of nodes in `neighbors` and `back_edges`. This can potentially be very expensive, as each `node` in `neighbors` and `back_edges` can contain its own set of `neighbors` and `back_edges`. You may want to store pointers to nodes instead.

For example, you could use:

```
std::set<node *, Comparator> neighbors;
std::set<node *, Comparator> back_edges;
```

Instead of:

```
std::set<node> neighbors;
std::set<node> back_edges;
```

Where `Comparator` is:

```
struct Comparator {
  bool operator () (const node * a, const node * b) const {
    return !a || b ? *a < *b : false;
  }
};
```

Taking a step further, you could update the `graph` class to contain:

```
std::set<std::shared_ptr<node>, Comparator> node_set;
```

Instead of:

```
std::set<node> node_set;
```

Where `Comparator` is:

```
struct Comparator {
  bool operator () (
    const std::shared_ptr<const node> & a,
    const std::shared_ptr<const node> & b
  ) const {
    return !a || b ? *a < *b : false;
  }
};
```

Then `node` could be updated to contain:

```
std::set<std::shared_ptr<node>, Comparator> neighbors;
std::set<std::shared_ptr<node>, Comparator> back_edges;
```

Another alternative would be to represent the graph using an adjacency matrix instead.

Comment: I also thought about this but when I am using a random string with the size 1, the graph can max have 26^2 edges, which shouldnt take more than 16GiB of RAM. Or am I wrong with this?

Comment: @Exagon: The graph can have 26^2 edges, but your data structure duplicates most of the information because of extra node copies. You could have exponential blow up in memory if the depth of the chains of copies is comparable to the size of the graph.